# Is there a SASS equivalent for this LESS code? Variable with multiple styles

Tags: sass

Is there something similar in Sass than I can use to achieve this?

```
@discount-title:{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
};
.discount {
    @discount-title();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're known as **mixins** in Sass.

http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6

This is how the same code will look in sass:

```
@mixin discount-title() {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.discount {
  @include discount-title();
}
```

Comment: except you don't need the (), that is @ mixin discount-title { stuff }, 
.discount {  @ include discount-title; }

Comment: yep, that's correct! the brackets are for variables if you have any :P